# Swift: How to print a tree level by level without using join or higher order functions?

Tags: swift, string, algorithm, loops, data-structures

## Tree class

```
class TreeNode<T>{
    weak var parent: TreeNode?
    var children: [TreeNode] = []

    var value: T

    init(value: T){
        self.value = value
    }

    func add(_ child: TreeNode){
        self.children.append(child)
        print(children)
        child.parent = self
    }  
}
```

## print Tree

```
extension TreeNode{        

    func printTree() -> String{
        var returnString = "\(value)"
        if children.isEmpty == false{
            returnString = "{" + returnString + "{"
            for child in children{
                print("child count: \(children.count)")
                print("before: \(returnString)")
                returnString = returnString + "," + child.printTree()
            }
        returnString = returnString + "}"
        }
        if children.isEmpty == false{
            returnString += "}"
        }

        return returnString
    }
}
```

## Example with problem

```
let world = TreeNode(value: "World")
let america = TreeNode(value: "America")
let asia = TreeNode(value: "Asia")
let northAmerica = TreeNode(value: "North America")
let southAmerica = TreeNode(value: "South America")

world.add(america)
america.add(northAmerica)
america.add(southAmerica)

print(world.printTree())
```

> {World{,{America{,North America,South America}}}}

## Problem

The `,`  after every `{` is unnecessary. But it's needed in between two elements. I'm thinking of removing it from the first element by knowing the index, but don't think that's a pretty solution. Is there any other alternative?

I know I can just do something like:

```
extension TreeNode: CustomStringConvertible {
  public var description: String {
    var s = "\(value)"
    if !children.isEmpty {
      s += " {" + children.map { $0.description }.joined(separator: ", ") + "}"
    }
    return s
  }
}
```

<sub>☝️copied from [RW](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Tree)</sub>

But I don't want to use higher order functions nor I want to use [`.joined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690077-joined)

Comment: If you are experimenting with implementing common data structures in Swift, I'd suggest looking into implementing a (Binary) Tree using recursive enums with associated values :) It's quite a "Swifty" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension TreeNode: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        if children.isEmpty { return "\(value)" }
        var string = "{\(value){"
        var separator = ""
        for child in children {
            string += separator
            separator = ","
            string += child.description
        }
        string += "}}"
        return string
    }

}
```

Comment: `var separator = ""
        for child in children {
            string += separator`

so that's your whole trick (updating the separator value). Very nice. Would you lost interview points that way? I mean every time you're assigning a value to `separator`

Comment: I don't understand “Would you lost interview points that way?” If you mean “Would I count it against a candidate in a job interview?”—no, I would not count it against them. This is a toy problem and your solution constraints (no `joined`, no higher-order functions) do not apply to the real world, so I would not penalize other choices that make the solution simpler.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little bit more wordy :) where I replaced printTree with my own two methods

```
func describeNode() -> String  {
    var string: String
    switch children.count{
        case 0: string = ""
        case 1: 
            let child = children[0] 
            string = "{\(extractNode(child, andAppend: "}"))"
        default: 
         string = "{"
        let max = children.count - 1
        for i in 0..<max {
            let child = children[i]
            string.append(extractNode(child, andAppend: ","))
        }
        string.append("\(children[max].value)}")
    }
    return "\(string)"
}

private func extractNode(_ node: TreeNode, andAppend suffix: String) -> String {
    var string = "\(node.value)"
    if !node.children.isEmpty {
        string.append(node.describeNode())
    }
    string.append(suffix)
    return string
}
```

And I used the following test case

```
let world = TreeNode(value: "World")
let america = TreeNode(value: "America")
let northAmerica = TreeNode(value: "North America")
let southAmerica = TreeNode(value: "South America")

world.add(america)
america.add(northAmerica)
america.add(southAmerica)
america.add(TreeNode(value: "Central America"))
northAmerica.add(TreeNode(value: "Canada"))
northAmerica.add(TreeNode(value: "USA"))

print(world.describeNode())
```

which printed *{America{North America{Canada,USA},South America,Central America}}*